# Turn by turn navigation in Google map with in the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing the application in which i need to show **turn by turn navigation on the google map** . I have searched lots of document but nothing i can find. I have take the route from the **google map direction api** based  on the transit type selected by user. Now i need the step by step navigation and move the map same like google map. but not able to find any document. Should it possible in ios?

If it is not possible then is there any document that point it? And is there any alternative of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's terms of service for their mapping api does not allow turn-by-turn navigation, please see  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms 10.4.c.3

Last I looked (which was a while ago) Apple maps, here (by nokia) and some private mapping services (such as skobbler by telenav http://developer.skobbler.com/#tour) will allow you to do this.